# Speed up for loop in numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I am looking for accelerating this loop in numpy but I find no obvious pattern to do so:

```
for index1 in range(1, len_route):
        time_diff_matrix[index1, (index1+1):len_route] = \
            M[(index1-1):(len_route-2)] - \
            M[index1-1] + \
            N[index1-1, index1:(len_route-1)] + \
            N[index1, (index1+1):len_route] - \
            P[index1:(len_route-1)]
```

The rest of the time_diff_matrix is populated with zeros. It was a double-loop first. I got rid of one loop but I don't know how to get rid of the other loop. len_route is a large number.

Regards.

Comment: What's the typical value for `len_route`?  Shape of `M`?

Comment: can you provide a working minimal example ?

Comment: len_route is between 300 and 1200.

Comment: M is a 1-d array with length len_route-1

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using [`slicing` rows/columns](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) -

```
n = len_route
vals = M[:n-2] - M[:n-2,None] + N[:n-2,1:n-1] + N[1:n-1,2:n] - P[1:n-1]
r,c = np.triu_indices(len_route-1,1)
time_diff_matrix[r+1,c+1] = vals[r,c-1]
```

Another approach to avoid using `np.triu_indices` and using `np.triu` instead -

```
time_diff_matrix[1:n-1,2:n] = np.triu(vals)
```

Verify results -

```
In [265]: # Setup inputs
     ...: S = 10
     ...: M = np.random.randint(11,99,(S))
     ...: N = np.random.randint(11,99,(S,S))
     ...: P = np.random.randint(11,99,(S))
     ...: time_diff_matrix = np.zeros((S,S), dtype=int)
     ...: len_route = N.shape[0]
     ...: 

In [266]: # Original approach
     ...: for index1 in range(1, len_route):
     ...:     time_diff_matrix[index1, (index1+1):len_route] = \
     ...:         M[(index1-1):(len_route-2)] - \
     ...:         M[index1-1] + \
     ...:         N[index1-1, index1:(len_route-1)] + \
     ...:         N[index1, (index1+1):len_route] - \
     ...:         P[index1:(len_route-1)]
     ...:     

In [267]: # Proposed approach
     ...: time_diff_matrix_out = np.zeros_like(time_diff_matrix)
     ...: n = len_route
     ...: vals = M[:n-2] - M[:n-2,None] + N[:n-2,1:n-1] + N[1:n-1,2:n] - P[1:n-1]
     ...: time_diff_matrix_out[1:n-1,2:n] = np.triu(vals)
     ...: 

In [268]: np.allclose(time_diff_matrix, time_diff_matrix_out)
Out[268]: True
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes a 40% speed improvement. There are twice more calculations but the numpy optimisation overcomes this.

Comment: @daguix Consider [`accepting`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it if this solved your problem?